# subset a matrix in a for loop with logical operator or (|)

Tags: r, list, for-loop, logical-operators

I am trying to make subsets of a matrix. Each subset depends on a set of logical conditions. For example the first subset of the first list (`R[[1]][[1]]`) corresponds to the last column of the matrix being equal to 1 or 3 etc. I would like to use that in a loop.

This is an example of the data I have:

```
l = list(
  list(c(1, 3),c(2, 3)),
  list(c(1,5),c(2,5,6,7),c(3,6,8),c(4,7,8))
)

a1 <- array(1, dim=c(12,10))
a2 <- array(1, dim=c(18,10))
v1 <- c(1,1,3,1,2,3,1,1,3,1,2,2)
v2 <- c(1,1,3,1,5,2,4,5,5,5,7,8,1,4,5,8,2,4)<br/>
m1 <- as.matrix(cbind(a1,v1))
m2 <- as.matrix(cbind(a2,v2))
m <- list(m1,m2)
```

This is the code I use:

```
R <- rep(list(list()),length(m))
  for(i in 1:length(m)) {
    for(j in 1:length(l[[i]])) {
      R[[i]][[j]] <- m[[i]][m[[i]][,dim(m[[i]])[2]] == l[[i]][[j]],]
}}
```

I get the following results which is not what I want:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[[1]][[2]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[[2]][[2]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[[2]][[3]]
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  8 
[[2]][[4]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  4
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  7
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  8
```

This is the result I would like to get instead:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
 [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
 [6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [7,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [8,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
 [9,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[[1]][[2]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
[4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
[5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
 [5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
 [6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
 [7,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
 [8,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [9,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[[2]][[2]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  7
[7,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  5
[8,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2
[[2]][[3]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  8
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  8
[[2]][[4]]
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  4
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  7
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  8
[4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  4
[5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  8
[6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

If you want the same to apply all elements of list `m`:

`k<-lapply(m,function(x) x[x[,11] %in% c(1,3),])`

```
> k
[[1]]
                          v1
 [1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
 [4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
 [6,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [7,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
 [8,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
 [9,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1

[[2]]
                         v2
[1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[2,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[3,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  3
[4,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
[5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was not exactly what I was looking for, but it helped me find the solution that I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for me using `%in%`:

```
R <- rep(list(list()),length(m)) <br/>
for(i in 1:length(m)) { <br/>
for(j in 1:length(l[[i]])) { <br/>
R[[i]][[j]] <- m[[i]][m[[i]][,dim(m[[i]])[2]] %in% l[[i]][[j]],] <br/>
}}
```